# How to mock static calls for member variable initialization?

Tags: java, powermockito

I am trying to create a test for a helper class but I am unable to mock a static call inside the helper class.

This is my class to be tested:

```
public class NoteHelper {

    private NoteService noteService = ServiceBuilder.getService(NoteService.class);

    public NoteResponse createNewNote(NoteRequest noteRequest) throws NotAuthorizedException {

        Note note = new Note();
        note.setContent(noteRequest.getContent());

        noteService.addNote(note); // throws NotAuthorizedException

        NoteResponse noteResponse = new NoteResponse();
        noteResponse.setContent(note.getContent());

        return noteResponse;
    }
}
```

Here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class NoteServiceHelperTest {

    String dummyContent = "ABCD";

    @InjectMocks
    private NoteHelper noteHelper;

    @Mock
    private NoteService noteService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    @PrepareForTest({NoteHelper.class, ServiceBuilder.class})
    public void createNewNoteTest() throws NotAuthorizedException {

        noteService = Mockito.mock(NoteService.class);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ServiceBuilder.class);
        PowerMockito.when(ServiceBuilder.getService(NoteService.class))
                .thenReturn(noteService);
        doNothing().when(noteService).addNote(any(Note.class));

        NoteRequest request = new NoteRequest();
        request.setContent(dummyContent);

        NoteResponse response = noteHelper.createNewNote(request);

        assertEquals(response.getContent(), dummyContent);
    }
}
```

From what I read I thought that the call to `ServiceBuilder.getService(...)` will get replaced and `noteService` will be using a mocked instance instead of a real instance.

The problem is that this is not happening and the `getService(...)` method is actually called and eventually fails due to some external system dependencies (`ServiceBuilder.getService(...)` needs to acquire some database connections and make HTTP calls to other systems before it returns the `NoteService` instance).

So my question is how can I use power mockito to mock the `getService(...)` and the `noteService.addNote(note)` calls ?

Comment: Perhaps it is required to put 'PowerMockito.mockStatic(ServiceBuilder.class)...' before 'MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)' !?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I get the same error :(